# Dynamic where clause for joined System.Data.DataTable in Linq C#

Tags: linq

I'd like to create a dynamic where clause for variable amount of columns. Can this be done?

I think I've looked at all the posts related to this topic but still cannot find the answer.

```
var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
              where table1["ColumnA"].ToString() != table2["ColumnA"].ToString() ||
                    table1["ColumnB"].ToString() != table2["ColumnB"].ToString() || 
                    table1["ColumnC"].ToString() != table2["ColumnC"].ToString()
              select table1;
```

Comment: What does not work? Side-note: don't name `DataRows` `table1` since that suggests that the variable is of type `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can logically add where clauses. Here's an extension method that does it 
(it's not mine, I saw it somewhere here on StackOverflow, a long time ago. I'll reference it when I find it)

```
Func<T, bool> And(this Func<T, bool> a, Func<T, bool> b) 
{ 
    return (T x) => a(x) && b(x); 
}
```

With it, you can iterate over the columns and add them to the where clause:

```
Func<string, bool> whereClause = x => true;
foreach(string columnName in dt.Columns.Select(x => x.ColumnName)
{
    string first = dt.Columns[columnName].ToString();
    string second = dt2.Columns[columnName].ToString();

    whereClause = whereClause.And(x => first.Equals(second));
}

var result = (from foo in bar select fooBar).Where(whereClause);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `System.Linq.Dynamic`([ScottGu's blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic)) in case of dynamic where clause:

```
var results = (from fruit in fruits 
    join car in cars on fruit.Id equals car.Id
    select new { fruit, car })
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where("fruit.ColA != car.ColA")
    .Where("fruit.ColB == car.ColB");
```

Or dynamicaly build expressions this using [extensions from `PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) writen by @joe-albahari. For example:

```
var predicate = 
    PredicateBuilder
        .True<Tuple<Product, Product>>()
        .And(t => t.Item1.ColA != t.Item2.ColA)
        .And(t => t.Item1.ColB == t.Item2.ColB)
        .Compile();    

(from fruit in fruits 
    join car in cars on fruit.Id equals car.Id
    select Tuple.Create(fruit, car))
    .Where(predicate)
    .Dump();
```

ps: full code available at [gisthub](https://gist.github.com/4259463)